# JMeter proxy connect error

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to set up script recording for JMeter following the [tutorial](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf).
I am able to start the proxy server and install the generated certificate, however when I try to connect to it I am getting the following exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:481)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:298)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:236)
```

Has anyone else experienced anything like this when setting up JMeter for script recording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to `%JMETER_HOME%\bin`
- Open *`system.properties`*
- Uncomment below line and update the value to `true`

  `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=false`

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `%JMETER_HOME%\bin`
- Open `system.properties`
- Uncomment below line and update the value to `true`

  ```
  java.net.preferIPv4Stack=false
  ```

This was working fine for me